# jQuery How to check if an entry has already exist in a table?

Tags: jquery, comparison

i'm using jquery to dynamically adding and removing rows of a table. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/1/).

My question is, how can i check if the entry (BOTH `output type` AND `output number`) has already exist in the table? so that i won't add 2 or more similar entries but update the existing one instead or just ignore or gave an alert...

I'm clueless about the checking part. Do I need a database??

```
if (textInput== ??existing entry??)
alert ("you have entered that output number for that output type");
// quit the codes below or something?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   function isExist(newEntry){
     return Array.from($('tr[id*=output_newrow]'))
              .some(element => $('td:nth(2)', $(element)).html() === newEntry );
    }
```

`newEntry` is the value of input text to add
Then :

```
$('.add').click(function () {

    textInput = "";
    $('.TextInput').empty();
    textInput =  $(this).prev('.TextInput').val();

    if(isExist(textInput)){
     alert("you have entered that output number for that output type")
    }else{

         //.....insert code
    }
})
```

### Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/MKfLU/27/

"but it applies to different selection option but same input number as well... can i do isExist (textInput)AND(type)? " 
If you want to embed type in the test :

```
function isExistx(newEntry,outtype){

  return Array.from($('tr[id*=output_newrow]')).some( el => 
    ( $('td:nth(1)',$(el)).html() === outtype ) && ($('td:nth(2)',$(el)).html() === newEntry)
  ); 

}
```

Then :

```
  if(isExistx(textInput,type)){
        alert('you have entered that output number for that output type')
    }else {

         $('#status_table tr:last').after(str);
    }
```

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/MKfLU/29/

Comment: hello thanks for the reply. but it applies to different selection option but same input number as well... can i do isExist (textInput)AND(type)?

Comment: not at all :) .As i am busy now,I will edit my answer later to support[isExist (textInput)AND(type)] .Be sure

Comment: yay! thanks! :D i tried to put that if-else into another function so that i can call it anytime i want... but it doesnt seem to append new row then :/ Also, how can i keep on updating the status those existing entries without having to adding new rows everytime it is updating? :s i know i can use setInterval but i think it will append infinite number of rows to my table when i loop it and i dare not to even try it :(

Comment: if it's work ,tick it to notify system that your issue was solved . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var flag = false;
$('#status_table tbody').find('tr').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(textInput == $('td:eq(2)', $this).text() && type == $('td:eq(1)', $this).text()){
        flag = true;
        return false;
    }
});
if(flag){
    alert('exists');
    return;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nKAja/2/)

Comment: hi Arun! thanks for the reply. i tried to input 1 for output and it works when i press "add" again. when i select "counter" and input 1, it can be added too. but then, i clicked on "add" again, it added counter 1 again too instead of showing "exists" :(

Comment: @yvonnezoe minor bug fixed

Comment: oh yay!! it works now. thank you so much. td:eq(2) and td:eq(1) refers to column 2 and 1?

Answer (score 2):

As you add the `<td>`, you could add a `data-unique-identifier` attribute to it using a combination of the type and number.

```
$td.data('unique-identifer', 'type: ' + type + 'number: ' + number);
```

Then before you add another row, you can use jQuery to see if any rows exist that match the same unique identifier.

```
var uid = 'type: ' + type + 'number: ' + number;
if ($('[data-unique-identifer=' + uid + ']').length > 0) {
    // already exists
}
```

Alternatively you could keep the information out of the DOM, and just maintain a javascript array of the information you have added.

When you add a new row:

```
myExistingRows.push({
    type: type,
    number: number
});
```

and to see if a row already exists before you add it:

```
function doesRowExist(type, number) {
    for (var index = 0; index < myExistingRows.length; index++) {
        var row = myExistingRows[index];
        if (row.type === type && row.number === number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/MKfLU/6/

Comment: thanks mchail :) so that would be called before $('#status_table tr:last').after(str); right? +1 btw :)

Comment: That's exactly right. Here's a working demo (you will get an alert popup if you try to enter the same information more than once): http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/MKfLU/6/

Comment: btw,i tried to put it into another function and call it to test but it doesnt seem to append a new row in that way :(

Comment: Can you paste a link to another jsfiddle and I'll take a look?

Comment: :) okay, here http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/DbwAy/2/ but this is definitely not going to work because it involves a "post"... just that i'm not sure if my method of writing a function is correct... it doesnt work on  the real program as well.

Comment: In that example, there is no need to define the `textExist()` function. You want those lines of code to execute immediately, so don't wrap them in a function. What's happening in your example is you are defining the `textExist()` function, but then not calling it, so its contents are never executed. Does that make sense?

Comment: umm, so instead of putting it in a function and call it in the if(reply==on) and else if (reply==off) condition, i should just paste those codes under the if and else if condition? and FYI, besides if (add_type == "output"), there will be something else like if (add_type=="input")... so what will be the best approach to do this? :)

Comment: I apologize, I had misread your code when I made that comment. Your function is appropriate, the issue is that you needed to pass in the `type` and `textInput` values so you could use them to see if a row already exists. I've updated your code: http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/DbwAy/3/

Comment: Thanks :D now that if i were to create a new array outputArray as in here (http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/Bsr5R/) to store just inputs from "output" type, i would also want to remove it from those 2 arrays when the "x" button is clicked (remove that row entry from table). i tried splice, but i don't think i'm doing it right. how can i find the exact element to be removed from the arrays?
"

Comment: I think you'll need to ask a new StackOverflow question at this point :) For a hint: you'll need to get the `type` and `textInput` values out of the `tr` that was clicked, and loop through your `outputArray` until you find a row with matching values. That's the one you can remove.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28930/discussion-between-mchail-and-yvonnezoe)